# jquery/javascript: hide div when click anywhere on page except for selected div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have div-1 and div-2. when a user clicks on div-1 div-2 is shown. This operates using jquery as a toggle function so when a user re-clicks div-1, then div 2 is hidden again. now i want to add a statement to my jquery that says if the user clicks to another area of the page so an area which is not div-1 then to also hide div-2. can someone please show me how i might do this as i am brand new to jquery and javascript.

thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('.notifications').click(function() {
       $('.drop_down_column2').toggle();
       return false;
   });
   </script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect a click outside an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
$('body').click(function() {
    $('.drop_down_column2').hide();
});
```

Because you are returning `false` from your `.notifications` click handler, jQuery will prevent propagation of the event up to the `body`.  So in essence, any time you click anywhere, except `.notifications`, your div will hide.